# how the browser interpret non-standard/custom html tag

Tags: html, angular

I'm new to front end development.just a question on how the browser interpret non-standard/custom html tag. Because when use Angular, there is a tag called:

```
<body>
  <app-root ng-version="xxx">
    <div>                        
       ...
       <ul _ngcontent-c0>...</ul>   
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

Below is my questions:

Q1-how browsers interprets `app-root`? should it be an error when browsers parse the html file? or does it mean that I can add any non sense tag into the html like `<NonSense></NonSense>` and the browsers just ignore it?

Q2-When browsers parse non-standard attributes like `_ngcontent-c0`? does the browsers just ignore them and I can add any nonsense attribute to html tag like:

```
<h1 non-sense-attr></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1. As you have guessed,  is not a standard HTML tag. This is a custom selector tag that refers to a particular component. It tells Angular where our component should be rendered. Once we finish creating it, our root component will load its template HTML between the  tags included above.

Q2. [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184761/angular-rendered-dom-html-custom-attributes), For more explanation about ViewEncapsulations [Refer this](https://medium.com/@hardikpthv/viewencapsulations-in-angular-component-ce48fedcf94c)

Comment: I know it is a selector, how does browsers interpret this non standard html tag

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Elements

[Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) are a set of web platform APIs that allows creating new custom, reusable, encapsulated HTML tags to use in web pages and web apps.

> Web Components is a suite of different technologies allowing you to
>   create reusable custom elements — with their functionality
>   encapsulated away from the rest of your code — and utilize them in
>   your web apps.

One of the features of Web Components is [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). With Custom Elements, a developer (or platform) can introduce non-standard HTML elements, which will be processed by most modern browsers.

### Custom Attributes

You can indeed add any custom attributes. The browsers ignore them. In the context of Angular, the custom attributes are added by the framework for [view encapsulation and projection](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/). In your example `<ul _ngcontent-c0>...</ul>` can be used (automatically by Angular) in the rendered CSS to apply specific styles to that particular `ul` element like so:

```
ul[_ngcontent-c0] { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Every angular project will have appComponent created by default which is the base component that renders the custom user created components.
- These components defines the various UI elements in the application. These UI elements are rendered in the HTML in user defined name.
- To recognize the base component that is appComponent which loads the other components, default name given by the app is app-root, as explained below on the component definition,

  ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })
  ```

Please go through the angular guide to understand further, http://angular.io/